# Nginx only recognises files in root dir (Permission denied on symlink'ed dir/files)

Tags: nginx, php

UPDATE -- This is driving me nuts (or back to Apache...)

The issue is definitely symlinks and permissions

When I setup symlinks to directories in the same tree, for example /var/www/html/html2 --> /var/www/html2 it works fine. Also /var/www/html/test_alias --> /var/www/html/test works fine. It's just when pointing out a different volume that I get 403. I have sprinkled all those directories with read and exec rights and nginx ownerships, but nothing works. I have also tried adding

sendfile off;
  autoindex on;
  disable_symlinks off;

but to no avail! There must be something fundamental I am missing??

---

OK so I'm a beginner with Nginx, however I have successfully setup a number of Apache websites, so this can't be that difficult right?

Well, not really. At least not for me. I have struggled for a couple of days while setting up a server that can interpret PHP code. Nothing fancy at all.

I have FINALLY a version of nginx.conf that somewhat works. It loads php and html in that order, and defaults to index.php and index.html.

My root is /var/www/html, owned by user nginx. Files in "html" loads OK, but when I symlinked a directory under "html", they won't load. Can anyone give me a hint about whats wrong?

This is my conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  index index.php index.html;
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    root  /var/www/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      root           /var/www/html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
}
```

Directory structure is:

```
/var/www/html
```

these files load OK

```
/var/www/html/mysite
```

these files are not found/loaded

It would be great if someone could give me a solution to this problem. And if you also know a good reference with simple config examples I'd love to hear about them. God knows there exist plenty with incorrect/outdated/plain confusing config examples.

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: Could be a permissions problem, they're pretty common. Copy the files from the symlink to the actual folder, as a test, setting permissions properly.

Comment: yes I forgot to mention that part. The error logs says 13: Permission denied. But the symlink and everything it points to is owned by nginx:nginx. But your comment triggered my tired brain, so I created a test subdir, with one php file in it, and that loaded OK. That means that the problems comes from the fact that I'm using a symlink??

Comment: What does the nginx documentation say on symlinks? Permissions can be tricky to work out sometimes.

Comment: You don't mention your OS, but I had similar issues with CentOS and SElinux. So your error log aside, also check your SElinux audit log.

Comment: Actually CentOS 7 is the OS running in a VM. Sysadmins choice I'm afraid. I will look into the log, if I can find it. Is it /var/log/audit/audit.log ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that your `php-fpm` process can access the PHP files from the place where you have made the symlinks? You should be able to test this with a simple PHP script at your `/var/www/html` directory which tries to open a file from your other volume.

Personally I would change the `root` directory to point directly to the actual place where the website root is, and not use symlinks for that purpose. And then use `alias` directives in `location` blocks to change the filesystem location for the URIs which are in different places.